# Six times on same foot

Tags: probability

After wearing a pair of socks a dozen times, what is the probability to the nearest hundredth that each sock has been on each foot exactly a half dozen times? This seemed an easy calculation but I got it wrong

I computed the total ways as $2^{12}$, then numerator = $\binom{12}6$. But since two feet we multiply times two.

Comment: I don't think you want to multiply by $2$.  Say we have a red sock and a green sock.  If the red sock has been on the left foot $6$ times, it has been on the right foot $6$ times, and  the green sock has been on each foot $6$ times also.

Comment: Aha .so I was right then with just 12c6/ 2^12?

Comment: Yes, you should have stopped there.

Comment: To me, it is helpful to think of the question as equivalent to asking what is the probability that we get $6$ heads when flipping a coin $12$ times.